# What library version is bundled with which version of the Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino, c, library

There are several libraries bundled together with the Arduino IDE. I wonder if there is a list which shows exactly which library (and bugfixes, code changes) where bundled with which Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is the [Arduino Changes page](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Changes) paired with the [official release notes](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ReleaseNotes).